# App in ionic framework without tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My app doesnot need any tab .Can i create a app without any tab using onic framework? But page will navigate on click of buuton.I have to first display a login page then on login i would want it to display list of items on click of it edit page is displayed.How can it be done?I have tried below code
 index.html

```
 <body ng-app="starter">
       <ion-nav-view name="login"></ion-nav-view>
       <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </body>
```

Then

```
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
     });
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 

    $stateProvider    
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'login': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });
```

Then in login.html

```
<ion-view title="Login">
 <ion-content class="has-header padding">
    login button and other inputs
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now on login home page should be displayed can anyone suggest how to route

Comment: Your question is not clear. The title doesn't match the question you ask. Generally if you want to show other page after login, add other `state` (aka `state('main')` and on button click use: or `ui-sref="<your state name>"` or `$state.go('<your state name>');` or `$location.path( '<your state + URL>');`

Comment: I suggest you to go to Ionic forum: http://forum.ionicframework.com/, hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I came here for the same question. Now I have the answer.

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 

  $stateProvider    
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

also, make sure you define your templates `home` and `login`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <p>This is home.</p>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="login.html">
  <button ng-click="logUserIn()">Log me in!</button>
</script>
```

and for dynamic interaction, you can use `$state` in your controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.logUserIn = function() {
    $state.go('home');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Do I have to add **$state.go('home');** for every page? Can't it be target by href?

Comment: Probably but I wouldn't know b/c I don't use Ionic/Angular anymore. Sorry.